# Uploading a document to Google Drive and setting its paper size

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I use the [Java library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) to upload an HTML file and convert it to native Google document. Here is the code:

```
String title = "Doc title";
byte[] data = <doc data>;
...

File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setTitle(title);
fileMetadata.setMimeType("text/html");
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("text/html", new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
mediaContent.setLength(data.length);

Drive.Files.Insert insert = service.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
insert.setConvert(true);
MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(true);

insert.execute();
```

Works great with one exception - it creates a document with paper size set to Letter. For my account the default is A4 and I want the newly created document to be in this format.

Does anyone know a way set the paper size of the uploaded document?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no options to configure the conversion to Google Docs, and there is no standalone API to manipulate Google Docs. You can change the page width and height via [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setPageHeight%28Number%29), but it would likely not be simple to integrate with your code.