# creation a document to Google Drive and change its paper size

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-api-php-client

I use the PHP library to upload and update an HTML file and convert it to native Google document

```
include_once ROOT.'/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$credentialsFile = ROOT.'/google-api-php-client/service_account.json';
if (!file_exists($credentialsFile)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Service account credentials Not Found!');
}

$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFile);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

/**
   * Проверка существования папки для документов
   */

$optParams = array(
  'q' => "name='Документы'"
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
exit('Нет папки для документов');
} else {
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
$papka_doc = $file->getId();
  }
 }
/**
   * Обращение к шаблону
   */

$optParams = array(
  'q' => "name='{$tpl_name}' "
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
exit('Нет шаблона');
} else {
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
$sh_id = $file->getId();
  }
 }
/**
   * Получение контента из шаблона
   */

$content = $service->files->export($sh_id, 'text/html', array(
'alt' => 'media' ));
$dd =$content->getBody();

$chto = array_keys ($replace);
$chto= $this->translit($chto);


$nachto =array_values ($replace);
$nachto= $this->translit($nachto);


$dd = str_replace($chto, $nachto, $dd);



/**
   * Создание основы для документа
   */
$fileId = $sh_id;
$doc_name = $tpl_name.'_'.date('dmY-Hi');
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
  'name' => $doc_name,
  'parents' => array($papka_doc)));
$file = $service->files->copy($fileId, $fileMetadata, array(
  'fields' => 'id'));
$new_file_id = $file->id;

/**
   * Вставка контента в новый документ
   */
$fileMetadata = array(
    'data' => $dd);
$filenew = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file = $service->files->update($new_file_id, $filenew, $fileMetadata);
```

it creates a document with paper size set to Letter. For my account the default is A4 and I want the newly created document to be in this format.
Does anyone know a way set the paper size of the uploaded document?

P.S.: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183561/uploading-a-document-to-google-drive-and-setting-its-paper-size) thread, but may have appeared a method?

Comment: I've searched through the docs but unfortunately, I didn't find any related example. As stated in the [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183561/uploading-a-document-to-google-drive-and-setting-its-paper-size), it's not yet supported. However, you can file a [feature request](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/TESSj1GH1Xw) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive contains files in what is called a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) it is basically a metadata list of information about the file.   Some of these fields can be updated some can not.  The fields that are write about state that on the page I linked above.

There is no information about paper size.  That is probably because drive doesn't care about paper size that is something the local machine sets at the time it prints the file.

Answer: No you cant set paper size for a file on Google drive

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Apps Script. It's a bit hacky, but should work. You'll need to :-

1. create an Apps Script function that uses the Document service (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setPageHeight%28Number%29 to manipulate the page parameters for a given document ID
2. Publish that script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content so that it can be called as an endpoint.
3. After you import your file as you are currently doing, G Drive will return the ID of the newly created file into `$file`. Use this ID (`$file->getId()`) to call the endpoint from step 2.